# Rのデータフレームで、同じ行の次の列の値と自分の値を参照して、置換を行う関数を教えて欲しいです！

Tags: r

Rのデータフレームで、同じ行の次の列の値と自分の値を参照して、置換を行う
簡単な方法
を教えて欲しいです！

下記画像のような処理をしたいです
(自分のマス==1&&同じ行の次の列のマス==0)を満たす場合、自分のマスを2に変更

[image: if(自分のマス==1&&同じ行の次の列のマス==0)、自分のマスを2に変更)]

Answer (score 0):

こんなのは思いついてる範囲かもしれませんが、…以降の条件もよくわからなかたので。

```
# データフレームの作成
df <- rbind(c(NA,NA,1,1,1),
            c(1,0,0,0,0),
            c(1,1,0,0,0),
            c(1,1,1,0,0),
            c(NA,NA,1,0,0))

# 行数でループ
for( i in 1:nrow(df)){
  # 列数でループ
  for( j in 1:(ncol(df) -1)){
    # 検証する要素のNA判定、NAを含まない場合でTRUE
    if(!is.na(df[i,j])){
      # dfの要素で1の次の列に0があるか判定
    if((df[i,j] == 1 ) && (df[i,(j+1)] == 0)){
      # TRUEなら1を2に書き換える
      df[i,j] <- 2
    }
    }
  }
}
```

NA要素を含んでいるので処理が煩雑です。
要素の数だけでループで確認しているので、要素が増えるとその分処理が遅くなります。
あまりエレガントではありませｎ。

Answer (score 0):

いろんなやり方があると思うのですが、
せっかくRなのでtidyverseを使ったやり方はいかがでしょう。

「書くコード量を減らす」を最優先に考えています。

```
tibble <- rbind(c(NA,NA,1,1,1),
            c(1,0,0,0,0),
            c(1,1,0,0,0),
            c(1,1,1,0,0),
            c(NA,NA,1,0,0)) %>% as_tibble

tibble %>%
  unite("combi", 1:ncol(tibble), sep="-") %>%
  mutate(modified = str_replace_all(combi, "1-0", "2-0"))
```

このような結果になります：

```
> tibble %>%
+   unite("combi", 1:ncol(tibble), sep="-") %>%
+   mutate(modified = str_replace_all(combi, "1-0", "2-0") )
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  combi       modified   
  <chr>       <chr>      
1 NA-NA-1-1-1 NA-NA-1-1-1
2 1-0-0-0-0   2-0-0-0-0  
3 1-1-0-0-0   1-2-0-0-0  
4 1-1-1-0-0   1-1-2-0-0  
5 NA-NA-1-0-0 NA-NA-2-0-0
```

後は必要に合わせて separate() など使って整形すれば元に戻すことも一行で可能です。

```
> colnames_bkp <- names(tibble)
> 
> tibble %>%
+   unite("combi", 1:ncol(tibble), sep="-") %>%
+   mutate(modified = str_replace_all(combi, "1-0", "2-0")) %>%
+   separate("modified", into = colnames_bkp)
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  combi       V1    V2    V3    V4    V5   
  <chr>       <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 NA-NA-1-1-1 NA    NA    1     1     1    
2 1-0-0-0-0   2     0     0     0     0    
3 1-1-0-0-0   1     2     0     0     0    
4 1-1-1-0-0   1     1     2     0     0    
5 NA-NA-1-0-0 NA    NA    2     0     0
```

"unite()/separate()"の組み合わせは本当にいろんな使い方が出来るので、
色々楽しんでみてくださいね。